# How to handle Window Based PDF

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've scenario like when clicking on one button its opening a Window Based PDF File:

[image]

I'm using **Gecko driver Version -21.0 Firefox Version -61.0.1 Selenium Stand alone Server -3.13**

I'm unable to switching to the window based PDF File getting error:

> java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed in Result

The above error is coming for "**driver.getWindowHandles()**" method

It's working for Chrome and IE but when I'm using Gecko driver Version - 20.1, I'm able to Switching the Window Based PDF.

Can anyone help me with this?

I want to handle it by using latest gecko driver -21.0

Comment: What's the purpose if proceeding to the PDF page?

Comment: here the purpose is after clicking the button the pdf file either should be downloaded automatically or it should open
But we need to handle it either download or window based
if i go with gecko driver 20.1, i'm able to switch
Just confirm to pdf is coming or not after clicking the button

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is difficult to perform operations on pdf by switching tabs. The best way is to download the pdf and perform operations on the downloaded file using some java library or pdf-parser.

This usual behaviour of pdf is due to an enabled feature of pdf js. Disabling that in the firefox profile may solve your issue

Update your Firefox profile solves this issue.

```
       FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

       profile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );
       profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true );
       profile.setPreference("pdfjs.enabledCache.state", false );
       profile.setPreference("pdfjs.enabledCache.state", false);
       profile.setPreference("pdfjs.migrationVersion", 2);

       profile.setPreference("pdfjs.previousHandler.alwaysAskBeforeHandling", true);
       profile.setPreference("pdfjs.previousHandler.preferredAction", 4);

       FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setProfile(profile);
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

which stops the pdf opening in new window and further you can implement a method to download the file and parse the downloaded file.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks Bhargav,
But when using gecko driver 21.0 with latest version fire fox 61.0.1
for window handling i'm getting "java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed"
when i'm debugging the code i'm getting the above exception for driver.getWindowhandle() statement
Could you please let me help in this

Comment: This code works fine in ff 58, I tested in ff 61 and noticed that we need few more preferences to make it work. I have updated the earlier solution. That should download the pdf file automatically, try that and let me know